# How to update Qt LCDNumber inside a while loop

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

First time using Qt so bare with me for being new and probably asking a dumb question.

The Qt application I am building is to connect to a table that returns values when polled. I am using ZMQ for the connection.

GOAL: The application will connect to the table, and consistently poll for the position and velocity information which then should update the two QLCDNumber fields to display the value.

I understand I need a signal and slot

- HOW do I create the connect to the function that performs the updates?

.h File

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <string>
#include <zmq.h>

#include "tableSocketMonitor.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void connectAndPoll();          // Connects to the Table and Polls for info.

signals:
    void updateValues(double p, double v); // Updates the GUI fields.

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    bool isConnected = true;       // Bool - Changes to true when connected to table.
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "tableSocketMonitor.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.hpp>

const std::string ipAddr = "tcp://*";

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("Position / Velocity GUI");
    setMinimumSize(331,221);

    connectAndPoll();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::updateValues(double p, double v){
    // update Position field
    ui->pLCD->display(p);
    // Update Velocity field
    ui->vLCD->display(v);
}

void MainWindow::connectAndPoll(){
        zmq::context_t context (1);                             // Creating context for connection.
        zmq::socket_t socket(context, zmq::socket_type::req);   // Setting socket with REQUEST type. Table is a REPLY type.
        socket.set(zmq::sockopt::routing_id, "gui");             // Setting the routing ID for the socket

        socketMonitor monitor;                                  // Creating monitor to check for socket events.
        const int events = ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED;                 // Only Event we are interested in. at this time.
        monitor.init(socket, "inproc://conmon", events);        // Initialize the monitor.

        // While the program is not connected to the rate table, attempt connection.
        while(!isConnected){
            try{
                socket.connect(ipAddr);                         // Connect to the ip address
                if(monitor.check_event(10)){                    // Wait 10ms - *IF* the CONNECT event kicks
                    isConnected = true;                         // Set the connection bool
                    continue;                                   // continue past the while loop
                }
            }
            catch(zmq::error_t err){                            // Catch any error
                cout << "ERROR: " << err.what() << endl;        // Output error
            }
            sleep(2);                                           // Sleep for 2s if not connected - then re-try
        }

        std::string posReq = "PPO";                             // Holds the position request
        std::string velReq = "PVE";                             // Holds the velocity request
        zmq::message_t posRep;                                  // Holds the position reply.
        zmq::message_t velRep;                                  // Holds the velocity reply.
        std::string::size_type posSize;     // alias of size_t
        std::string::size_type velSize;     // alias of size_t

        // DO-While loop to allow requests and replys while program is connected.
        do{
            // Get Table Positioning - Catch any error.
            try{
                // Send Position Request
                socket.send(zmq::buffer(posReq), zmq::send_flags::none);
                // Get Reply
                socket.recv(posRep, zmq::recv_flags::none);
            }
            catch(zmq::error_t err){
                // Catch any error and print it to console.
                cout << "ERROR: " << err.what() << endl;
            }
            // Get Table Velocity - Catch any error.
            try{
                // Send Velocity Request
                socket.send(zmq::buffer(velReq), zmq::send_flags::none);
                // Get Reply
                socket.recv(velRep, zmq::recv_flags::none);
            }
            catch(zmq::error_t err){
                // Catch any error and print it to console.
                cout << "ERROR: " << err.what() << endl;
            }

            // Data returned *should* be double type
            updateValues(std::stod(posRep.to_string(), &posSize), std::stod(velRep.to_string(), &velSize));

        }while(isConnected);

        // Clean up.
        socket.disconnect(ipAddr.c_str());
        socket.close();
        context.shutdown();
        context.close();
}
```

Main

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I don't see any signal/slot connection in your code. Are you by chance confusing socket connections with signal/slot connections? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: No, I understand I need to create a "connect". But I am not sure where to place it to operate and what all i need to include for both fields to be updated.

Comment: I am thinking it should be along the lines of ```connect(this, updateValues(), &ui, pLCD->display()) ``` and same for vLCD ?

Comment: You declared `updateValues()` as a signal, but defined and used it as a socket.
Qt's signal is a way to call some function (a slot), that has an appropriate signature.
Qt's slot is a function, that can be called directly or by connected Qt's signal.
The MOC makes the magic generating and additional *.cpp files during the compilation.
Signal-slot mechanism is a kind of subscription. You emit a signal and if there are some slots connected to the signal, they all will be called with the passed (by signal emitting) arguments.

Comment: The following article can be more helpful for you: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: For your case, you can just remove `signals:`  from your header.

Comment: Your loop, as implemented, obviates the need for a signal, but presents some problems. First, it's a tight loop, which could 1) block the event loop (preventing your UI from updating), and 2) trigger a WDT, depending on your OS. Second, I don't see a call to connectAndPoll(); how does this get executed?

Comment: @RinatGadelshin socket.connect is a ZMQ method - not the same as Qt's connect functionality. OR are you saying I should split the updateValues function into two? and call an ```emit updateVel(posRep);``` same for pVel LCD. From documentation, LCDNumber->display() is already a slot. So I should just have to emit the signal correct?

Comment: @mzimmers I removed the function call because it was causing the GUI to not populate. Just an empty black window would appear.

Comment: @mzimmers you're spot on with 1. That is whats happening when I remove updateValues as a signal - leaving as a pub function. Fields don't update and whole window spawns completely black. Is there a better way to do my loop so I can allow the event loop to continue its process while constant polling ?

Comment: (This is just off the top of my head, so don't get married to anything I say here.) I'd look at posting an asynchronous read on your socket, and connecting a function to the readyRead signal that reads the socket input, and calls your updater. With signals and slots, you often don't need loops in your application code. It takes some getting used to but it's a great design.

Comment: @ChipBrommer I don't see the entire code. Particularly I don't see where and how you call MainWindow::connectAndPoll(). If you use the function as the main event loop of your program, then your GUI can be frozen. To avoid it just add `qApp->processEvents()` after calling `updateValues()`.

About ZMQ connect, I know that it isn't a Qt's connect =)
I've pointed, that you declare `updateValues()` as a signal, but define and use it a simple function.

Comment: @RinatGadelshin thank you for your comments, I will try the processEvents and move updateValues as a public function instead of a signal. I did just edit the posts code in MainWindow::MainWindow so you can see where the function call is.

Comment: @ChipBrommer I sill don't see where and how you call `MainWindow::connectAndPoll()` =)

Comment: @RinatGadelshin .cpp file in the MainWindow::MainWindow function, after it sets the window title and size.

Comment: So, you'll get a frozen GUI. MainWindow() invokes almost infinitive loop and MainWindow::show() will never be invoked.
I suggest you split GUI code and logic code.
Logic's code must don't know about any GUI. It should has signals for delivering actual values to the QLCDNumber widget. GUI's code would connect its slots to the logic's signals in order to update widget's presentation.

Comment: @RinatGadelshin where would you suggest I call my ```connectAndPoll()``` function from?

Comment: @ChipBrommer it will be a bad but working solution.
1. `Q_SLOT ` before declaration of `connectAndPoll()` : (`Q_SLOT void connectAndPoll()`)
2. Replace direct call the function inside the constructor by a deferred invoke of it. Use `QMetaObject::invoke( this, "connectAndPoll", Qt::QueuedConnection, QGenericReturnArgument() );`.
3. add `qApp->processEvents()` after calling `updateValues()` inside the function.